# Resize logo to menu in CSS with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I have this css:

```
/* Global CSS styles */
body {
    background-color: #364f6b;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Styling the logo */
.logo {
    width: 1px;
    height: auto;
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
  
  
    <!-- Menu -->
    <link id="themeLink" th:href="@{/css/mystic-planets.css}"  rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <img th:src="@{/images/137364472_padded_logo.png}"  alt="mystic-planets" />
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

but the logo does not resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current CSS rule for the `.logo` class only targets elements that have the `logo` class, but in your HTML, the `img` tag does not have that class.

If you want to apply the CSS rule to your logo, you should add the `logo` class to the `img` tag like this:

```html
<img class="logo" th:src="@{/images/137364472_padded_logo.png}"  alt="mystic-planets" />
```

Then, your CSS rule should work. However, with `width: 1px;`, your logo might appear extremely small, so you might want to adjust the width property to your desired size.

```css
.logo {
    width: 100px;  /* Adjust to your preferred size */
    height: auto;
}
```